# ColdFusion locale specific currency inputs in forms using commas (ie french Canadian 2 222,22$)

Tags: coldfusion, locale, currency-formatting

Is there an easier/shorter way to convert the final comma of a currency input to a decimal.

Inputs look like 2 000,99 OR 2,000,99

MySQL wants them to look like 2000.99

```
<cfform action="commatest.cfm?gotime" onsubmit="commatest.cfm" method="post" name="waiv">
<cfinput type="text" name="commer">
<input type="submit" style="width:180px;" value="convertme" class="hide button">
</cfform>

<cfif isdefined("gotime")>

<!--- START SCRIPT --->
<cfset formentry = FORM.commer>
<cfset howlong = #len(formentry)#>

<cfif howlong GT 3>
<cfset leftlen = howlong - 3>
<cfset rside = #right(formentry, 3)#>
<cfset rside = ReReplace(rside,"[,]",".", "ALL")>
<cfset lside = #left(FORM.commer, leftlen)#>
<cfset lside = ReReplaceNoCase(lside,"[-$A-Z,]","", "ALL")>
<cfset lside = reReplace(lside, "[[:space:]]", "", "ALL") />
<cfset newb = #lside# & #rside#>

<!--- OUTPUT TO DATABASE (or webpage in this case) --->
<cfoutput> 
<h1>#newb# (number? #IsNumeric(newb)#)</h1>
</cfoutput>

<cfelse>

<cfoutput>
<h1>#formentry# (number? #IsNumeric(formentry)#)</h1>
</cfoutput>

</cfif>
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual there are several different ways to do this. I would probably do something like this:

```
<cfscript>
source1 = '2 000,99';
source2 = '2,000,99';

// remove ALL commas and spaces
example1 = REReplace(source1,"[\s,]","","all");
example2 = REReplace(source2,"[\s,]","","all");

// insert a decimal before the last two digits
example1 = Insert(".",example1,(Len(example1)-2));
example2 = Insert(".",example2,(Len(example2)-2));

writeOutput(source1 & " = " & example1);
writeOutput("<br>");
writeOutput(source2 & " = " & example2);
</cfscript>
```

That code gives the following output:

```
2 000,99 = 2000.99
2,000,99 = 2000.99
```

Of course this assumes that the last two digits are always going to be after the decimal point.

[Here is a gist of the code above](http://trycf.com/gist/f103f7d0c1241bdb92b3838d495be1ea/acf2016?theme=monokai).

Comment: You would think CF would have a built in functions to "convert (number|date) from format X to Y" by now ... :)

Comment: (Edit) @scott7ree - Is "2,000,99" actually valid? I did not think you could use "," for *both* a decimal and grouping separator ...

Comment: ColdFusion does have NumberFormat() and DollarFormat() but these examples are not "normal" on the input or output side.

Comment: (Edit) Well, they should be "normal" in the conventions of *some* locale ;-) The first example is actually valid according to [the standards for "fr_CA"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html), ie "space" (group or thousands separator) and comma (decimal separator) `LSParseNumber("2 000,99", "fr_CA")`. I am not well versed in all of the conventions for fr_CA, but the second example seems wrong to me ie using comma for *both* separators. In most locales, they two are different characters.

Comment: @Leigh "You would think CF would have..." -- I know you aren't new here. :-)

Comment: And I agree; can a comma be used like this? Is 2,000,99 valid?

Comment: @Shawn - Heh.. temporary insanity brought on by wishful thinking?

Comment: I agree 2,000,99 isn't valid...but I did want to account for the possibility.

Comment: Code works well on examples...but doesn't work on regular inputs (2000 or 2000.99).  In my case we have people using both formats...so I'll probably keep my code.